# Calculating confidence intervals and p values for odds ratio in CLMM2 (R)

Tags: r, logistic, confidence-interval

I have recently conducted an ordinal logistic regression using the `clmm2` function of the `ordinal` package in R.  I have been able to successfully derive the odds ratios for my predictors by exponentiating their respective betas.  However, I am unsure as how to now obtain the confidence intervals and p values for these ORs.  Typically I would use the `tab_model` function from the `sjPlot` package or the `fixef` method commonly used with `glmer` models, however, it appears neither can handle objects of the clmm or clmm2 class.

I noticed [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52819422/confidence-intervals-for-odds-ratio-in-clmm-clmm2-r) was posed but remained unanswered several months back (my output is quite similar to that presented therein).  Any thoughts or suggestions would be extremely helpful.

Much appreciated; thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `confint()`?

Comment: Thanks @user2974951 . Unfortunately, trying confint() on my clmm2 model simply provides the CIs for the StDev (while also noting that "clmm2 may not have converged"; though the model itself does converge previously).

Comment: The package manual indicates that `confint()` should return the CI for the model parameters. Also, to get the p-values you can use `summary()`.

Comment: Agreed, it should.  However, after a particularly long processing wait, `confint(myOrdinalModel)` simply provides a single set of CIs for the stDev and a series of convergence warnings: `"Warning messages:
1: clmm2 may not have converged:
  optimizer 'ucminf' terminated with max|gradient|: 0.0000169369951600873 
2: clmm2 may not have converged:
  optimizer 'ucminf' terminated with max|gradient|: 0.000015712320898149 
3: clmm2 may not have converged:
  optimizer 'ucminf' terminated with max|gradient|: 0.118254068719" `.  Any additional insight into the issue would be great.

Comment: For anyone reading in the future: the answers [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304833/how-to-calculate-odds-ratio-and-95-confidence-interval-for-logistic-regression) provide some workarounds.  Though still unclear as to why confint() is not providing the expected output.